# Extending Object causes jQuery error

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, prototype

So I wrote a function to extend Objects to count how many entries are within them, so it may be used as such:

```
test = {"foo": "bar", "baz": 7, "darth": "maul"}

test.count()
=> 3
```

I wrote the code as such:

```
Object.prototype.count = function() {
  var count = 0, key;
  for (key in this) {
    if (this.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      count++;
    }
  }
  return count;
}
```

This is my first attempt at extending with prototype, and I'm getting this error from within jQuery.js:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function () {
  var count = 0, key;
  for (key in this) {
    if (this.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      count++;
    }
  }
  return count; 
} has no method 'replace'
```

The stacktrace points back to where I call `css` on a jQuery object onLoad:

```
$img.css({left: 20, top: 50});
```

Not that I think there's anything specific about that line, but I thought it may be good to provide.

Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lesson in why it can be a bad idea to extend the prototype of native types. :)

Somewhere in `jQuery`, it's testing a generic object for the existence of a property called `count`, and then treating it as a string. Since you've now caused that property to always exist, it found it, but it wasn't a string (as it expected) and broke the code.

Comment: I've changed the function name a few times to random things with the same result. So, does this mean it's not possible to extend Object when using jQuery? I can write it as a straight function, but the extension made more sense to me (compared to `length` for strings)

Comment: It could be looking for any properties that it doesn't expect to be there. It's almost universally a bad idea to alter the prototype of `Object` (and to a lesser degree other types) since this affects *everything* that inspects object properties. Code like `if (myobject.count)  { ...}` is de facto standard for testing property existence. If you really want to use custom methods on a generic object, then just create your own prototype and use it instead of the native object.

Comment: Well that's just shotty. Thanks for the help

Comment: .. in the case of this error which you got on the (`css` method) I'd actually say this is probably also an example of sloppy code in jQuery. It should use `hasOwnProperty` to iterate through properties, and it appears it doesn't. But that doesn't change the rule; there's just too much risk in adding your own methods or properties to `Object`, and testing objects with just dot notation is not considered bad practice (so a common name like `count` would prob. trip you up even in exceptionally well written code)